# Regex how to get a full match of nth word (without using non-capturing groups)

Tags: regex

I am trying to use Regex to return the nth word in a string. This would be simple enough using other answers to similar questions; however, I do not have access to any of the code. I can only access a regex input field and the server only returns the 'full match' and cannot be made to return any captured groups such as 'group 1'

EDIT:
From the developers explaining the version of regex used:

> "...its javascript regex so should mostly be compatible with perl i
>   believe but not as advanced, its fairly low level so wasn't really
>   intended for use by end users when originally implemented - i added
>   the dropdown with the intention of having some presets going
>   forwards."

/EDIT

Sample String:

> One Two Three Four Five

Attempted solution (which is meant to get just the 2nd word):

```
^(?:\w+ ){1}(\S+)$
```

The result is:

> One Two

I have also tried other variations of the regex:

```
(?:\w+ ){1}(\S+)$
^(?:\w+ ){1}(\S+)
```

But these just return the entire string.

I have tried replicating the behaviour that I see using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) but the results seem to be different, particularly when changing around the `^` and `$`.

For example, I get the same output on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) if I use the altered regex:

```
^(?:\w+ ){1}(\S+)
```

In any case, none of the comparing has helped me actually achieve my stated aim.

I am hoping that I have just missed something basic!

===EDIT===

Thanks to all of you who have contributed thus far, however, I am still running into issues. I am afraid that I do not know the language or restrictions on the regex other than what I can ascertain through trial and error, therefore here is a list of attempts and results all of which are trying to return "Two" from a sample of:

> One Two Three Four Five

```
\w+(?=( \w+){1}$)
```

returns all words

```
^(\w+ ){1}\K(\w+)
```

returns no words atall (so I assume that `\K` does not work)

```
(\w+? ){1}\K(\w+?)(?= )
```

returns no words at all

```
\w+(?=\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+$)
```

returns all words

```
^(?:\w+\s){1}\K\w+
```

returns all words

====

With all of the above not working, I thought I would test out some others to see the limitations of the system

Attempting to return the last word:

```
 \w+$
```

returns all words

This leads me to believe that something strange is going on with the start `^` and end `$` characters, perhaps the server puts these in automatically if they are omitted? Any more ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your regex engine support variable length lookbehinds? `(?<=^\w+ )` or match resets `^\w+ \K`?

Comment: If even `\w+$` returns all words then you should provide more information, sample code, context, language... etc

Comment: I am attempting to get more information from the creator as to what language is being used as well as any other information that they are willing to share. I will update OP if/when I get answers.

Comment: Can you test the output of these 4 regex? (Two|Four), (\w+\s(?=Two)), ((?<=Two)\w+\s), (\w+\sTwo$). I think the ^ and $ are being stripped, and that all full matches are being returned. Also, is this input field in a webpage? If it is processed client side, then it is probably JavaScript, or probably Java if server side.

Comment: OK, so `(Two|Four)` & `(\w+\s(?=Two))`  does not return anything until either 'two' or 'four' are written, at which point the entire string is returned.

`((?<=Two)\w+\s)` Returns entire string

`(\w+\sTwo$)` Returns nothing, irrespective of string input.

The input field is in a webpage yes.

Comment: So I managed to get through to the developers and this is what they said:
"...its javascript regex so should mostly be compatible with perl i believe but not as advanced, its fairly low level so wasn't really intended for use by end users when originally implemented - i added the dropdown with the intention of having some presets going forwards."

Answer (score 1):

I don't known if your language supports positive lookbehind, so using your example,

> One Two Three Four Five

here is a solution which should work in every language :

`\w+` match the first word

`\w+$` match the last word

`\w+(?=\s\w+$)` match the 4th word

`\w+(?=\s\w+\s\w+$)` match the 3rd word

`\w+(?=\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+$)` match the 2nd word

So if a string contains 10 words :

The first and the last word are easy to find. To find a word at a position, then you simply have to use this rule :

`\w+(?=` followed by `\s\w+` (10 - position) times followed by `$)`

**Example**

In this string :

> One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Height Nine Ten

I want to find the 6th word.

10 - 6 = 4

`\w+(?=` followed by `\s\w+` 4 times followed by `$)`

Our final regex is

`\w+(?=\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TgpKnN/1)

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your suggestion(s), unfortunately, it has not succeeded, I have updated the original post explaining. Any further assistance you can offer would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use reset match (\K) to reset the position of the match and obtain the third word of a string as follows:

```
(\w+? ){2}\K(\w+?)(?= )
```

I'm not sure what language you're working in, so you may or may not have access to this feature.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your suggestion(s), unfortunately, it has not succeeded, I have updated the original post explaining. Any further assistance you can offer would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your language does support `\K`, but still sharing this anyway in case it does support:

```
^(?:\w+\s){3}\K\w+
```

to get the 4th word.

- `^` represents starting anchor
- `(?:\w+\s){3}` is a non-capturing group that matches three words (ending with spaces)
- `\K` is a match reset, so it resets the match and the previously matched characters aren't included
- `\w+` helps consume the nth word

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MmCgR4/2/)

And similarly,

- `^(?:\w+\s){1}\K\w+` for the 2nd word
- `^(?:\w+\s){2}\K\w+` for the 3rd word
- `^(?:\w+\s){3}\K\w+` for the 4th word
- and so on...

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your suggestion(s), unfortunately, it has not succeeded, I have updated the original post explaining. Any further assistance you can offer would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So, on the down side, you can't use look behind because that has to be a fixed width pattern, but the "full match" is just the last thing that "full matches", so you just need something whose last match is your word.

With Positive look-ahead, you can get the nth word from the right

```
\w+(?=( \w+){n}$)
```

If your server has extended regex, \K can "clear matched items", but most regex engines don't support this.

```
^(\w+ ){n}\K(\w+)
```

Unfortunately, Regex doesn't have a standard "match only n'th occurrence", So counting from the right is the best you can do. (Also, Regex101 has a searchable quick reference in the bottom right corner for looking up special characters, just remember that most of those characters are not supported by all regex engines)

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your suggestion(s), unfortunately, it has not succeeded, I have updated the original post explaining. Any further assistance you can offer would be welcome.